# How to get all element within a division using selenium or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, selenium

I need to get all elements within a division. The division loads data dynamically based on the selected value from a dropdown. So for each selected value there is a different set of elements within the division.
this is the HTML:

```
<div id="container1">
<div id="container1.1">
<input id="dropdown" type="select">//dropdown for dynamically selecting elements of container1.2
<options>1</options>
<options>2</options>
</div>
<div id="container1.2">
<input type="text" id="element1">
<button id="element2">
</div>
</div>//for container
```

selenium code:

```
List<WebElement> obj=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@id='Container']//*"));//to get all elements in division
        System.out.println(obj.get(0).getTagName());
        System.out.println(obj.get(1).getTagName());
```

This doesn't give the required result.  Im getting following error:

```
invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //[@id='Container']//* because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//[@id='Container']//*' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Comment: Error clearly says that xpath is not correct. You need to use the `options`. So the xpath `driver.findElements` should locate the dropdown

Comment: If it is unique then use :`List<WebElement> obj=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='dropdown']"));`

Comment: can you tell me how to give the right xpath in this case

Comment: @KishanPatel I dont know what all elements are going to load each time. I need something like: driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*")); this gives all elements in a page right? Similarly i just want all elements within a division

Comment: You won't know what is there in dropdown right?  But dropdown will be there always. M I right?

Comment: @KishanPatel The options in dropdown is not what Im asking. Im asking how to Id the textboxes or select boxes or buttons that load dynamically as a result of choosing an option from dropdown. I mean the contents of <div id=container1.2> keeps chanfing acc to option chosen. I want to Id those elements ...which are inside container1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as stated by the error message, your xpath expression is not valid. It should be

```
List<WebElement> obj=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='Container']//*"));
```

or you could use wildcards //*[@id='Container'] if the element is not specific to div.

Other way to list child element inside the container and maybe a bit better

1. `List<WebElement> parentElements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='Container']"));`
2. iterate the element, then use parentElement.findElements(By.xpath(".//*")) to get child elements from the parentElement. You could refer to this documentation https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*div[@id='Container']//*")); and it worked...... could u pls tell me the difference between //*div[@id='Container'] and //div[@id='Container'] ....how are they functionally different?

Comment: `*` is used when we are looking for an element having id = Container; whether that element is a div or any other html element

Comment: as stated by @kushal, * is wildcard, so if you don't really know what element that having id container, you could use //*, but if you know that it is div, it is better using //div,  since using * will scan all your html page (performance related) . One more thing, the usage is //*[@id=...] and not //*div

Answer (score 0):

$('.className').html();

much better

document.getElementsByClassName('className').innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

This gives all elements within a div....use "//" and NOT "/" the second time ..because it gives only elements of root type.

```
List<WebElement> obj=BaseClass.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='Container']//*"));
```