# Unable to scrape text from dropdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using python 3. I am trying to scrape the data from the "PROGRAMS/MAJORS" dropdown on the following url:

https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id=222178

Here is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Specify the path to your WebDriver executable
driver_path = 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\drivery\\chromedriver.exe'

# Instantiate a browser driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)

# Get the webpage
driver.get('https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id=222178')

# Wait until the page is fully loaded
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "programs")))

# Get the programs/majors data
programs_majors = element.text

# Close the driver
driver.quit()

# Print the scraped data
print(programs_majors)
```

The output shown is:

```
 PROGRAMS/MAJORS
```

which is the heading of the dropdown. What I want is the text in that dropdown, i.e. the details of all the programs. I'm stuck, please consider helping.

Comment: Consider using [the actual API](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/college-map-12007) for the data instead of scraping which introduces many places for failure.

Comment: I don't use Selenium, but, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43320261) - probably what you need are the elements contained in that div.

Comment: This is a duplicated question: [How to pick data from dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76253218/how-to-pick-data-from-dropdown)

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley - your link for the API does not contain the "college navigator" data, it contains geospatial / map data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do click on the link Programs/Majors and then access to table data, as

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id=222178")

try: 
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'programs')))
    
    #click on the link to the programs to expand the table
    programs = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[15]/div/div[1]/a').click()
    table = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[15]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody')    
    #get all the rows of the table
    rows = table[0].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")    
    #print an example of 5 rows
    for row in rows[:5]:        
        cols = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")        
        for col in cols:
            print(col.text)
        print("---row")

except Exception as e:    
    print('Error: '+repr(e))    
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Instead of using a local driver file, use webdriver_manager ( pip3 install webdriver-manager).

Comment: Error: NoSuchElementException('no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[15]/div/div[1]/a"}\n  (Session info: headless chrome=113.0.5672.93)', None, None)

Comment: If a search method don't work use another, for example `programs = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'PROGRAMS/MAJORS').click()`

Comment: I have to make the same change to next line as well? this one: table = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[15]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody')

Comment: no, that's just to locate the anchor tag that expands programs table.

Comment: Agricultural/Animal/Plant/Veterinary Science and Related Fields
---row
Agribusiness/Agricultural Business Operations
-
-
-
4
-
-
---row
Animal Sciences, General
-
-
-
4
-
-
---row
Category total
-
-
-
8
-
-
---row
Architecture and Related Services
---row
​

Comment: the output is now like my comment above, its at least something! do you have any idea why its only capturing some bits here and there

Comment: when i run the same code, now it is saying: Error: IndexError('list index out of range')

Comment: It gets exactly the content of that table in the variable rows and prints an example of 5 column by column. Now you can treat your data the way you want. Consider reading how to use selenium library and how to debug python code or code in general.

Comment: when i run the same code, now it is saying: Error: IndexError('list index out of range') –

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253661/discussion-between-pepe-n-o-and-analyst92).